# *ngIf to apply a class inside two *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to apply a class when my element is clicked, however it's within two `*ngFor`.

I thought of doing with multidimensional array but apparently this is not the correct way because it is applying the class to several elements.

I tried something like:

```html
<div *ngFor="let tabelaAnuncioContas of sortedData; let a = index">
    <tr *ngFor="let anuncio of tabelaAnuncioContas.data[0].anuncio; let i = index">
        <td><img [class.zoomImg]="zoomImg[a][i] == true" (click)="zoomImg[a][i]= !zoomImg[a][i]" [src]="anuncio.produto.foto_prin_1"></td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

TS:

```
zoomImg:[][] = [[]];
```

When I have more than one element in the array `sortedData` is returned:

> Cannot read property '0' of undefined

When I have only one element in the array `sortedData`, no error message is generated, but when I click on the element all elements apply the class.

**@Edit**

My json sortedData:
[image]

Comment: if you log zoomImg, is it as it should be ?

Comment: is showed only [[]]

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is coming from `<tr *ngFor="let anuncio of tabelaAnuncioContas.data[0].anuncio; let i = index">` this line where you have hardcoded `data[0]`.

Is `tabelaAnuncioContas` getting its value from an observable? If yes, then `tabelaAnuncioContas` is undefined or `tabelaAnuncioContas.data` is undefined in its initial state and hence you are getting this error.

**Solution:** Try making it async or keep another check like `tabelaAnuncioContas.data!=undefined && tabelaAnuncioContas.data.lenght > 0`

Comment: No, it's not a observable, but the data ever return a valid value.

Comment: My backend accidentaly make "data" an array, *ngIf don't solve my problem. I think my problem is in (click)="zoomImg[a][i]= !zoomImg[a][i]" . I don't think this is a correct syntax, but i also tried zoomImg[[a],[i]] and don't work

Comment: how are you setting `tabelaAnuncioContas`? Also kindly add its value json to your question.

Comment: check out my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxgxm2. If your array dimension are okay then it should work just fine.

Comment: updated the stackblitz, and everything to work just fine....... how are you setting `sortedData`?

Comment: you are setting you array   sty = [
    [true,true,true,true,true,true],
    [false,false,false,false,false,false],
    [true,false,true,false,true,false],
  ]
i'm setting   zoomImg:[][] = [[]];

Comment: how are you setting `sortedData`?

Comment: I'm setting with a http request. I receive this from the backend: this.anunciosB2w = res.body

      this.sortedData = this.anunciosB2w.slice();

Comment: `sortedData` is the whole response object. which you are looping through. Then in the second loop why are you using `tabelaAnuncioContas.data[0].anuncio`? Should it be `tabelaAnuncioContas.anuncio`?

Comment: because data is an array that contains only one element, ever. My backend do it wrong, this is why i have to do .data[0]

Comment: is your json like this -> `[ {data: [{0:anuncio:[{0:...}]}]} , {1:{current_page:'',...}} ]`? If yes, that is why you are getting an error cause your response array has 2 object, one with `data` attribute and the other one without. and hence it's `undefined` and you are trying to get `[0]` of undefined. Which is why you need to keep a check if `data` is `undefined`.

Comment: I put a one div with *ngIf before the *ngFor but i still receive Cannot read property '0' of undefined. I tried:

     <div *ngIf="tabelaAnuncioContas.data !== undefined">

Comment: can you create a stackblitz demo with hardcoded json data?

Comment: i answered my question

Answer (score 0):

I make a little different, but now i have what i want.

**HTML:**

```
<td><img (click)="aplicaZoomMiniatura($event)" [src]="anuncio.produto.foto_prin_1"></td>
```

**TS:**

```
  aplicaZoomMiniatura(event){

    let classList = event.target.classList;
    event.preventDefault()

    if(classList.contains("zoomImg")){
      this.render.setElementClass(event.target, "zoomImg", false)
      } else {
      this.render.setElementClass(event.target,"zoomImg",true);
    }
  }
```